# How to get perticular node value? in xml using php

Tags: php, xml

I am using xml data using a url & because the xml is too long I just want to check condition to get particular node values only :-

Here is my code :-

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$doc->load("https://retailapi.apparel21.com/RetailAPI/products?countrycode=au");

$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
/*foreach ($xpath->query("/Products/Product[Code='00122']") as $node)
{
    echo $node->nodeValue;
    echo "Hi<br>";
}*/

echo $xpath->query("/Products/Product[Code='00122']")->item(0)->nodeValue;
?>
```

As you can see that I already used foreach loop & successfully executed the condition but.....the thing is inside it, it prints whole data of that all the nodes of it's parent node.

Confused? :)

Ok no worries, just execute this url: `https://retailapi.apparel21.com/RetailAPI/products?countrycode=au`; please click on Proceed anyway button then wait for some time.

There are many Product tags...now I want the data of the following nodes :-
Id
Code
Name
Description

whose code=00122 that's the first product's data.

I applied foreach then it printed all node's data of that product. I applied simple single statement but then also it printed all node's data :(

And one more thing is can't it be done by simplexml_load_file function?

One more thing :- You can see I am loading url, so the thing is it will read the whole xml first. Can't we query in this itself so that it will only take only related product tags so the loading time can be reduced.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Could you share an excerpt of the relevant XML structure?

Comment: Hi Jack, Can you please tell me what excerpt means? If you want how xml is looking like......then it's this :- https://retailapi.apparel21.com/RetailAPI/products?countrycode=au I have already mention in question jack :)

Comment: A small but relevant part of the XML structure that you need to query.

Comment: Hi Jack, Here is a small part of the xml :-

Comment: @Kaushal: [edit] your question to include the small and relevant piece of XML. Your link doesn't load for me. Please read the [help] before asking any further questions.

Comment: <Products>
    <Product>
        <Id>8843</Id>
 <RowNumber>1</RowNumber>
 <Code>00122</Code>
 <Name>Cotton Drill Overall</Name>
    </Product>
    <Product>
        <Id>8844</Id>
 <RowNumber>2</RowNumber>
 <Code>00123</Code>
 <Name>Cotton Drill Overall123</Name>
    </Product>
    <Product>
        <Id>8845</Id>
 <RowNumber>3</RowNumber>
 <Code>00124</Code>
 <Name>Cotton Drill Overall12345</Name>
 </Description>
    </Product>
</Products>

My real problem is xml is very very long Jack. so I do not want to load whole xml. It is taking time but can't we query directly at load time?

Comment: Hi Madara, you are right but the thing is I have already mentioned every thing in my first question & another thing is comment section allow only a few characters. Another big issue is when I copy paste something then to convert in into code it's difficult here in stackoverflow.

Comment: I suggest you to please have a functionality in stackoverflow like whenever anybody asking a question then first there should be a textarea & outside it there should be a button titled "ADD CODE". When anyone clicks on it then one textarea opens & whatever user writes it should be automatically converted into a code. Then outside it there should be again one button titled "ADD TEXT" for entering  texts. Please suggest this to the programmers there...I will also take care for current code adding system Madara but whatever I suggested is also required :) Hope you will take it positively :)

Answer (score 0):

You're nearly there. Replace DOMXpath::query() with DOMXpath::evaluate(). It allows to use Xpath expressions that return scalars like strings. Now the second argument of evaluate() (or query()) is the context, so you can iterate all nodes from one expression and fetch the details using xpath expressions depending on a context node:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$doc->load("https://retailapi.apparel21.com/RetailAPI/products?countrycode=au");
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

$result = [];
foreach ($xpath->evaluate("/Products/Product[Code='00122']") as $node) {
  $result[] = [
    'id' => $xpath->evaluate('string(Id)', $node),
    'code' => $xpath->evaluate('string(Code)', $node),
    'name' => $xpath->evaluate('string(Name)', $node),
  ];   
}

var_dump($result);
```

A call like `$xpath->evaluate('Id', $node)` would return a list with all `Id` element nodes that are children of $node. The Xpath function `string()` casts the first node in this list into a string and returns it. If the list is empty the result will be an empty string.

Comment: Hi ThW, Many thanks for your answers. It worked nicely :) so my 60% problem is solved :) Now the only thing I want to ask you is...can we load only that particular data when we call to xml?

I mean this statement loads whole xml first right? It is taking time Thw :( then it gives answer.
    $doc->load("https://retailapi.apparel21.com/RetailAPI/products?countrycode=au");

Can't we do like query directly to xml at the time of call so that it grabs only required data so loading time can be reduced? :)

Comment: <products>
<product>
<id>1</id>
<code>c1</code>
<References Type="Array">
<Reference>
<ReferenceTypeId>258</ReferenceTypeId>
<Id>2361</Id>
</Reference>
<Reference>
</product>
<product>
<id>2</id>
<code>c2</code>
<References Type="Array">
<Reference>
<ReferenceTypeId>258</ReferenceTypeId>
<Id>2361</Id>
</Reference>
<Reference>
</product>
<product>
<id>3</id>
<code>c3</code>
<References Type="Array">
<Reference>
<ReferenceTypeId>259</ReferenceTypeId>
<Id>23</Id>
</Reference>
<Reference>
</product>
</products>
I want id & code of those products having ReferenceTypeId=258 & ID=2361 can we do that?

Comment: Only if the service supports it and in the way the service supports it. Here is a `countrycode` parameter in the url, maybe other are supported, too. Ask the service provider. Of course if you fetch all data, you can cache it locally and use the local xml file from the cache.

Comment: Hi Thw thanks. Now the last thing is I have given the xml above & I want two conditions to-gather to fetch the data. I have applied this logic but not wokring :-

    foreach ($xpath->evaluate("/Products/Product/References/Reference[ReferenceTypeId='258'] && /Products/Product/References/Reference[ReferenceTypeId='2361']") as $node)

Basically I want to check 2 two conditions that ReferenceTypeId=258 & ID=2361 then fetch that product's data otherwise skip that product. So I stuck with how to give 2 conditions :)

Comment: Here is no `&&` in Xpath, You can provide several expressions using the `|`. (Much like the comma in css selectors.)

Comment: Hi Thw, Thanks for your all answers. I really appriciate your knowledge & your help :)